# How to show an external hard drive as offline

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive, offline-files

Googling this question is not giving me relevant searches so i'm asking here.

I recently upgraded my laptop by switching the 1TB sshd with an 240 GB SSD , i got an hard drive enclosure and now i'm using the 1TB to store all my data like iTunes , few games , files etc .

For some reason all my shortcuts(They get deleted automatically) and steam forgets that this drive is removable and i have to re add the steam library.

**What i want is for the external drive to permanently be visible in my pc but whenever i remove it , it should just become offline and not disappear**(The drive should be visible even if its not connected.

lenovo Y50 with latest stable build of win 10
External hard drive enclosure is a transcend

Comment: If you map a network drive then it will be visible always. You cannot do this in usb drive.

Comment: Then is there a possibility to make this a network drive?

Comment: wow thanks for the inspiration , i just made this drive sharable then went into network and mapped this drive as a network location and volla it shows up permanently :-)

Comment: @Zany 
Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: actually i tried this for sometime but there are some inconsistensies for example itunes still forgets about the library , steam works fine now though i will wait for sometime explore more options then il write an answer

Comment: making the external drive as sharable will cause problems for example whenever i connect other external drives the network location latches on to the first drive i connect. i don't think there is a solution to this problem.